# Datatable showing '1' after reloading the table and not the actual table data until I manually refresh the page

Tags: laravel, datatables

This is what I am getting after adding the value in datatable...I want complete table to be displayed but I am not getting that until I manually refresh the page...But data is getting added for sure...which I can see after refreshing the page...

Comment: Welcome to SO .. take a look this https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: I tried datatable reload